# Action of certain endomorphisms on Pontriyagin dual

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $R$ be a finite ring and $F$ be an algebraically closed field in which $|R|$ is invertible. Does there exists an $F$-valued character $\chi$ of $(R, +)$ such that every character $\psi$ is of the form $\psi(a) = \chi(ab)$ for some $b \in R$? If not, does the statement hold when $R$ is commutative (or under any other reasonably nice assumption)?

This is true when $R$ is a finite field. I believe that the statement in this case follows from the non-degeneracy of the trace form over the prime field contained in $R$.

Any references would be really helpful.

Motivation: This appears when we study representation theory of unipotent groups. Suppose $U$ be the subgroup of unipotent lower triangular matrices in $GL_n(R)$. Then elements of the form $E_{\chi} = \sum_{M \in U} \chi(M_{2,1})M \in F[U]$ appear naturally where $\chi$ is an $F$-valued character of $(R, +)$. There is nothing special about $M_{2,1}$, one can work with any closed "root subgroup". Now conjugating $E_{\chi}$ by an element of the cartan subgroup yields $E_{\chi(.b)}$ for some $b$ and so it becomes useful to know whether all characters can be obtained in this way.

Comment: I put an answer below, but I must say that now I regret it. The question seems entirely random and unmotivated.

Comment: This appears naturally when we study representation theory of unipotent groups. Suppose $U$ be the subgroup of unipotent lower triangular matrices in $GL_n(R)$. Then elements of the form $E_{\chi} = \sum_{M \in U} \chi(M_{2,1}) M \in F[U]$ appear naturally where $\chi$ is an $F$-valued character. There is nothing special about $M_{2,1}$, one can work with any closed "root subgroup". Now conjugating $E_{\chi}$ by an element of the cartan subgroup yields $E_{\chi(.b)}$ for some $b$ and so it becomes useful to know whether all characters can be obtained in this way.

Comment: A reference is James's book on representations of general linear group.

Comment: My previous comment was harsh, but too many questions on this site are not well motivated. There are $\aleph_0$ many arbitrary questions, and a great deal of those appear here. I see now that yours is indeed motivated. It will be useful (for you, first of all) if next time you put a question you will try to explain its importance in the first place.

Comment: You are right. I'll just edit my question and add the above as a motivation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call a character $\chi$ *(left) generating* if every character is of the form $\psi(a)=\chi(ab)$ for some $b\in R$. It turns out that, when $R$ is finite, a character is left generating if and only if it is right generating (every character has the form $\psi(a) = \chi(ba) $ for some $b\in R$).

The answer to your question is as follows:

> A finite ring $R$ has a generating character if and only if $R$ is a finite [Frobenius ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Frobenius_ring).

For a proof, see, for example:

*Thomas Honold*, MR 1831096 [**Characterization of finite Frobenius rings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/PL00000451), *Arch. Math. (Basel)* **76** (2001), no. 6, 406--415.

When the ring is finite and commutative, this is equivalent to $R$ having a multiplicity-free socle, or $R$ being a direct product of finite local rings with simple socle. (see *T. Y. Lam*, MR 1653294 [**Lectures on modules and rings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-0525-8) , Thm. 15.27, and more generally §§15, 16 for more characterizations and examples and non-examples.)

Your question is quite natural and appears in other contexts. For example, it appears naturally when studying Gauss sums over arbitrary finite rings, as in a series of papers by Lamprecht (cited in Honold's paper), and in:
*Fernando Szechtman*, MR 1916077 [**Quadratic Gauss sums over finite commutative rings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jnth.2001.2752), *J. Number Theory* **95** (2002), no. 1, 1--13.

This property of finite Frobenius rings is also relevant to coding theory, see

*Jay A. Wood*, MR 1738408 [**Duality for modules over finite rings and applications to coding theory**](http://muse.jhu.edu/journals/american_journal_of_mathematics/v121/121.3wood.pdf), *Amer. J. Math.* **121** (1999), no. 3, 555--575.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, Frieder! This answers my question completely.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a commutative counter example.

Fix a prime $p$, let $k=\mathbb{F}_p$ and let $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,xy)$.
Let $m=(x,y)<R$. Then $R$ is a 3-dimensional $k$-vector space, $m$ a 2-dimensional subspace and every additive character on $R$ could be identified with a $k$-functional.

Fix a character $\chi$ and view it as a functional. Fix an element $0\neq b_0\in m\cap \ker(\chi)$. Note that $\chi$ vanishes on $Rb_0=m\cap\ker(\chi)$.
It follows that $|\{\chi(\cdot b)\mid b\in R\}|<|R|$. Since the dual group has $|R|$ elements, there exists some character $\phi$ such that there is no $b$ satisfying $\phi(\cdot)=\chi(\cdot b)$.

Comment: This may not work though as $\chi$ may not vanish on $R b_0$. In fact we have a non-degenerate $\mathbb{F}_p$-valued bilinear form on $R$ given by $(a,b) = f(ab)$ where $f \colon R \to \mathbb{F}_p$ is "sum of coefficient function". Choose a non-trivial character $\chi$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Then the map from $R$ to the Pontriyagin dual given by $a \mapsto \psi_a$ is an isomorphism. Here $\psi_a(b) = \chi((a,b))$ . So if all this is right then the result should be true for the ring you mentioned.

Comment: @rohitna for your last comment, with your notation, I believe $\psi_0=\psi_{x-y}$. Thus $a\to \psi_a$ is not an isomorphism. Note that indeed $x-y$ is in the kernel of your bilinear form.

Comment: @rohitna note that for every $b\in m$, $Rb=kb$. It follows that if $b\in\ker(\chi)$ then $Rb\subset\ker(\chi)$. In particular, $Rb_0\subset\ker(\chi)$, that is $\chi$ does vanish on $Rb_0$.

Comment: Great, it works! The bilinear form I mentioned above is not non-degenerate. I am accepting your answer.

Comment: Maybe I should mention: a character $\chi$ on a ring $R$ will have the property you seek iff its kernel does not contain any non-trivial ideal. On a field for example, any non-trivial character will do.